# After using `shiftRows()` (Apache POI) lines below lost their merge settings

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I encountered a problem after using `shiftRows()` method, the lines below lost their merge settings. I noticed that if I append n rows, the same amount of rows (n) below are perfectly fine, but rows n+1, n+2, ... are unmerged.

I tried to add as many rows as there are in the excel file. The result was promising because merging problem was solved, but I had too many rows in the middle of file. So I tried to delete the unnecessary ones. But again, cells unmerged after deletion.

Maybe someone had the same problem?

My code:

```
public void readXLS() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{ 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:/JetBrains/test.xls"));
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    sheet.shiftRows(27, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 5, true,true);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/JetBrains/test2.xls");
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I was using 3.15 and now I upgraded it to 3.16, but it's all the same. If I add 5 empty rows, next 5 rows are okay, but the rest is bad(unmerged).